# update fields of object if changed angular

Tags: angular

i have a component that has to update an object if the fields change

i have made in onInit a get method to have all my data from database and then update fields if they change

which is the correct way of updating something?

```html
<div class="mb-2 alternate-warning-checkbox-wrapper">
  <mdb-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isRed" [default]="false">isRed</mdb-checkbox>
</div>

<div class="mb-2 alternate-warning-checkbox-wrapper">
  <mdb-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isToday" [default]="false">isToday</mdb-checkbox>
</div>

<div class="mb-2 alternate-warning-checkbox-wrapper">
  <mdb-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isImportant " [default]="false">isImportant</mdb-checkbox>
</div>

<button type="button" mdbBtn class="btn-sm" (click)="updateItem()" 
color="dark-green" mdbWavesEffect>Save</button>
```

ts code:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemService } from '@app/_core/api/item.service';

@Component({
            selector: 'app',
            templateUrl: './app.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
           })
export class App implements OnInit {

  @Input() isRed: boolean;
  @Input() isToday: boolean;
  @Input() isImportant : boolean;

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService,) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemService.getItem(id)
  }

   updateItem() {
     let item = [this.isRed, this.isToday, this.isImportant];
     this.itemService.updateItem(item)
   }        
}
```

service:

```js
updateItem(item: Item) {
  return this.apiService.put(`${this.resourceUrl}/update`, item);
}
```

Comment: Hi, but you are already using a seperate service and do DI in your component. So that is the correct way of doing. But I think you need so subscribe it. And using observables.

Comment: You have many typos in your code. `updateSupplier` and `supplier` should be `updateItem` and `item`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to implement `OnChanges` on the component.

```
export class App implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    // ...
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes here will contain all the input fields that have changed with their previous and current values
    this.updateItem(changes.item.currentValue);
}
```

Reference: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges